# The definition and direction of an energy function, related to the direction of a trajectory, for the ode $\ddot x + 2\epsilon \dot x + x = 0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, parametrization

This is from Glendinning's book *Stability, Instability and Chaos*, Example 1.2.

For the ode $\ddot x + 2\epsilon \dot x + x = 0,$ let $y = \dot x$, let $E(x,y)$ be a conserved function (like energy) $\frac12(x^2+y^2)$, then $\frac{dE}{dt} \leq 0. \quad(R1)$

It is argued that from this we expect 'all trajectories tend to minima of $E$ .. (0,0).'

$\\$

Why is the argument valid?

It seems that $E(x,y)$ does not decrease along the curve described by $E(x,y) = C$, but along any trajectory $(x(t),y(t))$ described by the above ode (*proof*: (R1) shows that the changes of $E$ and $t$ are opposite, and so along the positive direction of the curve $t$ increases suggesting $E$ must decrease?), without exception. And so the direction of $E$'s decreasing could be used to indicate the rough direction of the trajectories.
Therefore, it seems reasonable to argue that the trajectories would end up somewhere $E$ is small.

But why necessarily (0,0) where $E$ is minimum. Would not it be possible that a trajectory stop midway?

$\\$

Besides, the reason that $E$ is called the energy is that it describes the movement of points along the trajectory? Must it also be a conserved function? Can $E$ be any other such function? How to define 'conserved' for an energy function?

BTW, is this (a function decreasing along parametrized curves+conserved) actually the more accurate definition of energy than those in the common conception? And how is it related to the energy in differential geometry and Hamiltonian mechanics, where the geodesic is indicated by the minimum of energy function? Are the two energies consistent?

Comment: This is due to the dissipation term $2\epsilon \dot x$

Comment: @Cesareo Thanks. I know the the term would cause the energy to decrease. But why the energy function is defined this way?

Comment: Multiplying by $\dot x$ we have

$$
\frac 12(\dot x^2+x^2)+2\epsilon\int \dot x^2 dt=c_0
$$

Comment: Then $\dot x^2+x^2$ will remain inside any given ball with radius $\sqrt{2c_0}$

Comment: @Cesareo I see that E will be a bit smaller than it is without the dissipation term. And also E would not be constant along the curve. But why don't we define E to be, for example, $\frac 12(\dot x^2+x^2)+2\epsilon\int \dot x^2 dt$?

Comment: You ask why the argument is valid. Well, as it stands, it's *not* a valid rigorous argument, and that's exactly what the author himself writes: “It seems reasonable to expect [...]” followed by “**This idea will be justified in Chapter 2**” (my emphasis). So all your doubts should (hopefully) be resolved in Chapter 2!

Comment: @HansLundmark
Thanks. I guess it should be so. But I am also asking why $E$ is defined this way and its relation to Hamiltonian mechanics, the second part of my question is not discussed in the book.

Comment: According to the chapter 2, the energy function above is Lyapounov function. I've not seen its relation to energy. I will come back to this problem later.

Comment: "But why don't we define $E$ to be, for example, $\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2+x^2) + 2\epsilon\int\dot{x}^2\,{\rm d}t$?"

You need a function of two variables, $E = E(x,y)$, so that it makes sense to compute it along solutions to the ODE, i.e., $t\mapsto E(x(t),\dot{x}(t))$. The parameter $t$ cannot be part of the definition of $E$, unless you're thinking of a non-autonomous situation (in which case, for $E = E(t,x,y)$, one would consider $t\mapsto E(t,x(t),\dot{x}(t))$, which has no reason to be conserved).

Comment: @IvoTerek 1) Why two variables? It can be one or any, right? For example, if we let $E = \frac12 \dot x^2$, and if $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, then $E = \frac{\dot x_1^2+\dots+\dot x_n^n}2$, and so we have n variables. $\quad$ 2) Why in the non-autonomous situation ($t$ is included) $E$ cannot be conserved?

Comment: The answer might be about 'conservative fields in the manifold' which 'have the property that the line integral is path independent' https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07196.pdf, so in non-autonomous situation, the integral along a path between two points would depend on $t$, not just the position $(x, y)$, and so $E$ cannot be conserved.

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is defined this way in association to the energy of a mechanical system, acceleration or force equal to the gradient of the potential energy and a friction term. Or one could see the equation as a perturbation of the conservative case $ϵ=0$.

For a Lyapunov functional you could more generally also use
$$
E=\frac12\dot x^2+px\dot x+\frac{q}2x^2
$$
leading to
\begin{align}
\dot E&=(\dot x+px)\ddot x+p\dot x^2+qx\dot x
\\
&=-(\dot x+px)(2ϵ\dot x+x)+p\dot x^2+qx\dot x
\\
&=(p-2ϵ)\dot x^2+(q-2ϵp-1)x\dot x-px^2.
\end{align}
So that for instance $p=ϵ$ and $q=1+2ϵ^2$ gives
$$
E=\frac12(\dot x+ϵx)^2+\frac12x^2,~~\dot E=-ϵ(\dot x^2+x^2),
$$
which gives a more strict descent condition.

Comment: Thanks. This $E$ also satisfies the definition of a Lyapounov function. $\quad$
If we say $F$ or $\ddot x$ is proportional to $dE/dx-f$ (note it is not $dE/dt$), where $f$ is friction (supposed to be small), then the energy (or more exactly, work (and work-related potential energy) only, no heat included) $E = \int \ddot x dx = \int \ddot x \dot x dt = \frac{\dot x^2}2=\frac{y^2}2$, so why we have $\frac {x^2}2$ here?$\quad$

Comment: ... My thought is that perhaps the position here is defined as $r(t)=(x(t), y(t))$, and so replace $x$ with $r$, we have $E = \frac{\dot r^2}2=\frac{\dot x^2+\dot y^2}2=\frac{y^2+\dot y^2}2$ (dot product), this seems close, but it is still not the same, (and it seems we need to replace $y$ with $v$ such that $x = \dot v$,) why?$\quad$
Also, can we regard the dissipation term in $\frac 12(\dot x^2+x^2)+2\epsilon\int \dot x^2 dt=c_0$ (@Cesareo) as heat? If so, then the first integral = constant here can be interpreted as that work+heat is conserved?

Comment: I'm not sure how you make your physical analogies. $\frac12\dot x^2$ is the kinetic energy, $\frac12x^2$ the potential energy. Indeed the friction term removes energy from the particle and, usually, dissipates it as heat. // Lyapunov functions need to be coercive, so that they have, among others, bounded level sets. // The whole construction above is to move from "non-increasing" to "strictly decreasing", without further consideration of the phase dynamic. // Note that $r\dot r=x\dot x+y\dot y$, so that your formula for $\dot r^2$ is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I will read more about Lyapunov function and come back later.

Comment: I mentioned 'work (and work-related potential energy' above; it seems that according to https://math.univ-angers.fr/~campesato/ens/1920/line_integrals.html, energy here is the integral along a path plus a constant (due to the arbitrary choice of starting point of the integral), and they correspond roughly to work (or kinetics/potential energy gained by work) and to other parts of the energy. This explanation seems to solve my puzzle, since if energy is a multivariate function, then $dE = Adx+Bdy+\dots$. So $E = \int A dx + f(y,\dots)$ suggesting (perhaps only) part of $E$ is the line integral